# How to handle a Media Stream in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

A really cool new feature in recent browser versions is HTMLMediaElement.captureStream() (this has recently been shipped in Chrome).

Now I understand how it works on the client side. You can reroute the stream to other HTMLMediaElement. However, I want to be able to send it to the server and handle it in Node.js.

How could this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle it"? What do you want to do with it in Node?

Comment: Send it to another browser using Socket.io

Comment: Like all MediaStreams, you can send it through [webRTC](http://webrtc.org/)

Comment: Right, but isn't there a simpler way without web RTC?

Comment: I don't understand? This is exactly the sort of thing webRTC is designed for.

Comment: But let's say I don't want to use Web RTC. What then....

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to use webRTC, you could potentially use the MediaStream recording API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

Once you have the `Blob` objects you could send this data to Node using Websockets, distribute them back to browsers, re-assemble the Blobs, and play back the media.

However you couldn't stream these Blobs as they may not be individually playable. For that, you'll need webRTC.